# Yocto kernel patch fails with git am

Tags: kernel, yocto, patch

Problem with patching kernel. Used devtool extract to get at kernel source code

then modified one file and git commit within devtool context

then git format-patch against commit HEAD -1, copied resulting patch to recipes-kernel/files in bbappend recipe “files” folder

then added the patch file to bbappend recipe . The patch is correctly formatted as a subsequent devtool extract followed by git am  succeeds …

however bitbake virtual/kernel fails to apply the patch complaining that the file to be patched does not exist in the index

Tried bitbake virtual/kernel which failed as indicated above